# Alterando os campos primitivos e as constraints modify com MARIA DB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Os comandos **modify** e **change column** são utilizados para mudar tanto os campos primitivos quanto as *constraints* e nome do campo.

```
alter table pessoa modify column profissao varchar (30) not null;
alter table pessoa change column prof profissao varchar (30) ;
```

Porém, quando utilizo:

```
 alter table pessoa modify column profissao varchar (25) not null default '';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> alter table pessoa modify column profissao varchar (25) not null default '' Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'profissao' at row 1    0,083 sec

Answer (score 0):

Seu comando:

> `alter table pessoa modify column profissao varchar (25) not null default '';`

O problema está em tentar aplicar a restrição `not null` em uma tabela que já possui nesse campo um valor `null`.

Antes de realizar seu comando de alteração da estrutura, altere os valores do campo `profissao` de forma a satisfazer a restrição a ser implantada.

```
update pessoa set 
  profissao = ''
where 
  profissao is null;
```

Agora que os dados já satisfazem a restrição, você prossegue com a alteração da estrutura:
`alter table pessoa modify column profissao varchar (25) not null default '';`

### Sobre o erro `Error Code: 1265` mencionado:

> alter table pessoa modify column profissao varchar (25) not null
> default '' Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'profissao' at
> row 1 0,083 sec

A mensagem de erro exibida não ajuda a encontrar o verdadeiro problema, pois dá a entender que o problema seria o campo com 25 caracteres não suportar os valores já existentes, ou seja, que existiria algum texto com mais de 25 caracteres.
Vale ressaltar que se esse campo em questão tiver atualmente 50 caracteres, por exemplo, e um texto contendo 35 caracteres, ao tentar diminuir o tamanho do campo para 25 caracteres, aí realmente ocorreria o erro `1265. Data truncated` indicando que haveria perda de informação, visto que estaria tentando diminuir o tamanho do campo para uma quantidade de caracteres inferior a algum valor presente naquele campo.